# Gephi on Mac 10.9.2

Tags: macos, gephi

I am having a problem running Gephi on Mac OS X 10.9.2. I just installed Java 8. Any thought as to why the program will not load when clicked on? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give us more information like any error messages. (e.g. execute the program in a Terminal to see whether there is any error output). Without any further information noone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

java 8 is not supported by Gephi. You have to install Java 6 for OSX by this link: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572.

After you've installed java 6 try this:

1. Locate your java home: it should be in       `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/` 
   and copy the path.
2. Open gephi.conf file. You can find it in: `/Applications/Gephi.app/Contents/Resources/gephi/etc/gephi.conf`
   you can open it, by terminal using this command: 
   `nano /Applications/Gephi.app/Contents/Resources/gephi/etc/gephi.conf`
3. change the line containing: `#jdkhome = "java-path"`, remove the # and replace "java-path" with your java home folder's path.
4. Save gephi.conf and launch Gephi.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the last nightly build

https://github.com/gephi/gephi

Bests.-